# How to pass object or list created through a for loop into JSON.stringify?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, for-loop, stringify

```
useEffect( () => {
        let allCryptoFuturesSymbols = {}
        getOrderRestrictions().then((result) => {
            let listOfSymbols = result.symbols
            for (let num in listOfSymbols) {
                let elt = listOfSymbols[num]
                const symbol = elt["symbol"]
                Object.defineProperties(allCryptoFuturesSymbols, {
                    [symbol]: {
                        value: symbol,
                        enumerable: true
                    }
                });
        })
        console.log(allCryptoFuturesSymbols)
        console.log(JSON.stringify(allCryptoFuturesSymbols))
    }, [])
```

The output of the first log is correct and expected, and the second is an empty object: {}. If you stringify a manually-defined object there is no problem, but the object created via this for-loop does not behave the same way.

Comment: Can you show the full code with the loop?

Comment: Title and shown code do not align. One talks about a (not shown) loop. The other shows defineProperties. And none of the code shows JSON.stringify being called. Include a *minimal reproduction case*,  remove the non-relevant code, and update the title/question.

Comment: JavaScript has no dictionary type. What you're referring to is an Object.

Comment: @user2864740 I addressed your comments.

Comment: Move the declaration of `allCryptoFuturesSymbols` into the `.then` callback.

Comment: @YaakovAinspan that didn't work. The solution is to make sure the orderrestrictions await is fulfilled before the population of the symbols object begins.